# Store a row of two dimensional-array together at a time

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, store

I have a problem of storing all values of a row that i read from file csv together at the same time to put into 2 dimensional-array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main()
{    
    char *filename = "pb0.csv";
    char str[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *fpr;
    fpr = fopen(filename, "r");
    int i,j;
    const int row = 449;
    const int column = 6;
    int family[row][column];
    int c,d,e,f,g,h;


    if (fgets(str, BUFSIZE, fpr) != NULL) {
        while(fscanf(fpr, "%d; %d; %d; %d; %d; %d", &c,&d,&e,&f,&g,&h) != EOF){
            for(i=0;i<row;i++){
                for(j=0;j<column;j++){
                    //add code here
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //printf("%d",n);
    fclose(fpr);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have at least two problems with the code you show. The first is that you read *and ignore* the very first line. The second is that you don't handle errors very well. The third is that you read one "line" from the file, and then you iterate over *all* of the 2d-array (when you only need to set values of a single row).

With a few changes you can solve all three of these problems (which the third is what you seem to ask about):

```
int current_row = 0;

// Read all lines in a loop
while (fgets(str, BUFSIZE, fpr) != NULL)
{
    // Parse the line we just read, read directly into the row
    if (sscanf(str, "%d; %d; %d; %d; %d; %d",
               &family[current_row][0],
               &family[current_row][1],
               &family[current_row][2],
               &family[current_row][3],
               &family[current_row][4],
               &family[current_row][5]) == 6)
    {
        // Parsing successful, advance to the next row
        ++current_row;
    }
}

// All data read from the file
// The number of lines that was actually read and successfully parsed is in
// the variable current_row

// Example iterating over all records that were read from the file
for (int i = 0; i < current_row; ++i)
{
    printf("family[%d][0] = %d\n", i, family[i][0]);
}
```

Comment: First line is the title of each column in csv file so it has no problem. Anyway, thank for your improvement!! I will try to test it!!